# How to print an array using printf

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Im currently trying to overload a method called printIntArray so that it accepts 2 parameters: the array and an integer, n, where n indicates the number of elements to be printed per line. I need to use printf and a right-justified field width of 5. If n <= 1, printing 1 element per line.
What I have so far is:

```
public static void printIntArray(int a[ ], int n){
    if(n <= 1);
    System.out.printf(%5d);
```

How could I get the if statement to print the next one while using printf?

Comment: `if(n <= 1);` lose the semi-colon. Also, the `printf` usage is incorrect. You need to pass a string and a value: `System.out.printf("%5d", n);`

Comment: Remove `;` at end of `if` statement and indent the next line to show that it is controlled by the `if` statement. --- Also, you will need a loop, you know that, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printIntArray(int a[ ], int n) {
    for(int i =0, j =0;i< a.length ; i++, j++){
        System.out.printf("%5d", a[i]);

        if (j == n){
            System.out.println("");
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}
```